# Center text in parent with 2 variable width views aligned to sides

Tags: android, android-layout

One of the requirements of the project I'm trying to wrap up is to reproduce an iOS UI feature akin to the Navbar.

(I realize that this is bad from the Android design perspective but there is nothing I can do about it.)

For those of you who don't know what I'm trying to accomplish [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Art/ui_navbar.jpg) is an example. The point is to have a TextView bar that is always centered while having the possibility of two variable width buttons aligned to the left and to the right. The title must still be centered even if one of the two buttons is gone.

This behavior isn't too difficult to accomplish by using a dummy invisible view to force the left and the right "components" to have the same width.

The use case where the above doesn't work is when the title is too long to be logically centered (and or the left button is missing.) In that case my solution forces the title to be ellipsized way to quickly. The desired behavior is for the title to extend into that empty space.

Any help would be appreciated. I realize that this explanation may have been rather confusing. I would be more than glad to clarify any points.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a RelativeLayout? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

With a RelativeLayout, you could have the TextView fill the entire width of that top bar, except for some layout_margin to the left and right to leave space for the buttons. The left and right buttons would sit on a second layer of the RelativeLayout (below the TextView).

Comment: theelfismike, with your approach there is no accounting for variable width buttons. For instance, what if there are no buttons at all and we have a really long title? In that case the TextView should be given the entire width of the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Candy, I don't think it's that simple. What if the title is really long? I believe that this layout will display the left part of the title over the left button and the right part under the right button, won't it? I was under the impression that if you use the layout_ attributes that position views relative to the parent then you lose the ability to detect other views inside the RelativeLayout